# How to add Graphics in Gui as a Panel below a button panel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have been trying to have a simple layout of a `JPanel` with some `JLabel`s and buttons, and below it, a graphic that shows up.

I've created the graphics using a class extending `JComponent` with `paintComponent` inside it and then this class is instantiated and added to the frame after the first panel. Only the graphics show up.

I tried spacing the graphic, doesn't change anything. I know for a fact the buttons work because when I comment out adding the Graphics object component it displays only the buttons. What do I do?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Frame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame yipee = new JFrame();

        final JLabel title = new JLabel("Create your Character");
        title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        final JLabel chooseCol = new JLabel("Choose Color");
        final JLabel chooseGen = new JLabel("Choose Gender");
        final JLabel ranWeap = new JLabel("Random Weapon");

        color = (Color.WHITE);

        isMale = true;

        ranWeapTriggered = false;

        JButton ranWeapBut = new JButton("Fancy");

        JRadioButton male = new JRadioButton("Male");
        male.setSelected(true);

        JRadioButton female = new JRadioButton("Female");

        ButtonGroup genBut = new ButtonGroup();
        genBut.add(male);
        genBut.add(female);

        JButton pickCol = new JButton("Click Me");

        KnightComponent kc = new KnightComponent();
        //call method if random weapon pressed
        if(ranWeapTriggered)
        {
            //character.trigger()
            ranWeapTriggered = false;
        }

        JPanel options = new JPanel();

        options.add(title);
        options.add(chooseCol);
        options.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
        options.add(chooseGen);
        options.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
        options.add(ranWeap);
        options.add(pickCol);
        options.add(male);
        options.add(female);
        options.add(ranWeapBut);
        //options.add(dis);



        yipee.add(options);
        yipee.add(kc);


        class PickColorListener implements ActionListener 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick Color", color);
                if(color == null)
                    color = color.WHITE;
            }
        }

        class ChooseGenderListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public ChooseGenderListener(String gIn)
            {
                gender = gIn;
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(gender.equals("male"))

                    isMale = true;
                else
                    isMale = false;
            }
            private String gender;
        }

        class RandomWeaponListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ranWeapTriggered = true;
            }
        }



        ActionListener l1 = new PickColorListener();
        pickCol.addActionListener(l1);

        ActionListener l2 = new ChooseGenderListener("male");
        male.addActionListener(l2);

        ActionListener l3 = new ChooseGenderListener("female");
        female.addActionListener(l3);

        yipee.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        yipee.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        yipee.setVisible(true);
        yipee.setResizable(false);
    }    

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static Color color;
    private static boolean isMale;
    private static boolean ranWeapTriggered;
}
```

.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class KnightComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Knight k = new Knight(0,200);
        k.draw(g2);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"What do I do?"* _ Provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: If your "graphic" is just an image, you can create an ImageIcon and then display it easily as a JLabel.

Comment: A "guess" would be that you are adding your components to a `BorderLayout` and adding them all to the default position, meaning that it's likely only the last component added is showing up...but I'm guessing, my crystal ball is broken...

Comment: @markspace *" JComponent with paintcomponent"*...

Comment: @markspace This is for school and my teacher said not to use JLabel.

Comment: Yep, as @MadProgrammer predicted, your program has some serious layout management issues such as your ignoring the layouts being used by your components, especially your JFrame. You will want to read the tutorials on how to use the layout managers, in particular the BorderLayout which a JFrame uses by default.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not using a BorderLayout but should I be? I'm really new to GUI so I'm not very aware of the customs.

Comment: Yes you **are** using BorderLayout, you're just not realizing it and are ignoring the implications. Again, find and read the tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not using a BorderLayout

Actually, you are, `JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` by default, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more detaiols.

The immediate solution might be to do something like...

```
yipee.add(options, BorderLayout.NORTH);
yipee.add(kc);
```

But because `KnightComponent` doesn't provide any sizing hints for the layout manager to use, it will be sized to `0x0` automatically.  You should override it's `getPreferredSize` method and return an appropriate default size

You've also broken the paint chain and this is going to result in some serious weridness, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: what do you mean by breaking the paint chain?

Comment: Painting is made up of a series of chained method calls, which all together, prepare and paint the component, but not calling the `super` method, you've broken the paint chain and weirdness will insure...see the linked articles...

Comment: I've read the linked articles and I don't understand what I'm missing here, should I be calling a super as a constructor for some parent class? should I be using super to call another method?

Comment: 1- You're override `paint`, this generally discouraged for a number of reasons (like breaking the paint chain), you should be overriding `paintComponent` 2- You should be calling `super.paintComponent` as the first statement within the `paintComponent` method, before you do any painting

Comment: and also I've used the BorderLayout.NORTH which basically fixed the problem, except the bottom part of the first component is cut off, can I extend the size of the north region?

Comment: *"But because KnightComponent doesn't provide any sizing hints for the layout manager to use, it will be sized to 0x0 automatically. You should override it's getPreferredSize method and return an appropriate default size"*

Comment: What am I passing super.paintComponent()? When I try to pass Graphics g it says bracket needed around Graphics?

Comment: Pass it the same `Graphics` context that the original method received...just like you would for any `super` call...